# How do I install a vpn on raspberry pi3 debian?

Tags: pi-3, software-installation, vpn

I have installed the defaults from NOOBS that came with the Canakit, have networking and browser working ... the only instructions I've found for ipvanish vpn setup so far use the outdated media center, I've installed Kodi v17.1 and it does not have the repository choices indicated in the media center instructions. I do have an ipvanish account, don't really want to downgrade to the older media center.

tia for any guidance on this setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoops, found it myself! Here's the answer:

https://support.ipvanish.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2761743-setting-up-openvpn-on-openelec-kodi

Note that openelec 8 will work,  this is the v17 of Kodi. I had previously installed Kodi v17 from the command window in the original noobs setup, but made a new sd card boot image with openelec per instructions in link above.

Once installed, the config has selections for many vpn providers as well as ipvanish.

Comment: Seeing as the solution worked for you, it would be appreciated if you marked your answer as correct to close the loop as it were.

Comment: ok... I clicked the check-mark button assuming that's what is needed

Comment: This answer still hasn't been marked as correct are you sure you marked it as correct? You should see a green tick appear.

Comment: there is a circle (to accept this answer) with a checkmark, it does turn green when I click it.  Also in the next area below, I see a box to the right  side with my FB profile picture that says "answered May 25 at 13:40".  Hope this helps.